# which sentence is largest and how many number contains

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace MyCSharpLearning
{
    class StringProject
    {
       public int LargestSentenceInformation(string i)
       {
           string[] txt = i.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ',' });
           var largeS=txt.Order          
       }
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           StringProject n = new StringProject();
           string str1 = Console.ReadLine();           
           Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a coherent question

Comment: formatting..... Thank you to whomever is editing.

Comment: i am new in C# programming. i want to how to write code "which sentence is largest and how many word contains". thnx

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You code doesn't explain what you are trying to do

Comment: And what is a sentence here? Please explain what your inputs are and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As far as I can understand this: The input is a string that may contain many sentences. He wants to determine (1) which sentence has the largest word count and (2) how many words the largest sentence contains.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a question from someone's programming homework to me...

Comment: using System;
    namespace MyCSharpLearning
    {
        class StringProject
        {           
           public static void Main(string[] args)
            {               
               string i = Console.ReadLine();
               string[] i = i.split(new char[]{'?','.','!'});
               var LargestSentence=i.OrderByDecending;/*not working*/
               int LargestSentenceWordNumber=largeSentence.length;
               Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: thats right @Ginosaji

Comment: sorry for unclear question as i am new learner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close to getting there.  This is easiest if you use the System.Linq namespace:

```
string[] txt = i.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ',' }); //this part you had correct
var stringsOrderedByLargest = txt.OrderByDescending(s => s.length);
```

stringsorderedByLargest will now contain be sorted from longest to shortest.  If you want to count how many words a string has, just do another split, but this time on ' ' and look at the  Count property of the resulting collection.